# Custom HTML attributes in MVC3 Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, html, model, data-annotations

I want to create a Model:

```
public class TestModel
{
    Microdata(Data = "data-test=this is a test!")]
    public bool Test { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the view:

```
@Html.DisplayForModel()
```

The result i'm looking for is something like this:

```
<label>Test:</label> <input type="checkbox" data-test="this is a test!" />
```

I've already created a custom attribute class, but this didn't produce anything.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class MicrodataAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string Data { get; set; }

    public RouteValueDictionary GetAttributes()
    {
        var attributes = new RouteValueDictionary();

        if (this.Data != null)
        {
            string[] kv = this.Data.Split(',');
            attributes.Add(kv[0], kv[1]);
        }
        return attributes;
    }
}



public class MetadataProvider : DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider
{
    protected override ModelMetadata CreateMetadata(IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes, Type containerType, Func<object> modelAccessor, Type modelType, string propertyName)
    {
        var metadata = base.CreateMetadata(attributes, containerType, modelAccessor, modelType, propertyName);
        var additionalValues = attributes.OfType<HtmlPropertiesAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (additionalValues != null)
        {
            metadata.AdditionalValues.Add("HtmlAttributes", additionalValues);
        }
        return metadata;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would it? There's no code that uses your attribute...

Read the blog post below - it describes how MVC uses metadata and has an example of a custom `object` template you will need to write:

http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html

Comment: I don't understand what you mean when you say there is no code that uses my attribute??

The whole point to using Models in MVC is to model your db or view or whatever for your application. 

These Models are going to be created dynamically and view just the same. Also, I need to use custom HTML5 data dash attributes.

Comment: @JasonFoglia - No code in MVC framework is using your `HtmlProperties` attribute.

Comment: How is this possible when there is data validation using html5 data dash attributes? ex: data-val Is there no way to manipulate data validation?

As you already know there is somewhat of a way to do this. You sent me a link, here's another http://ruijarimba.wordpress.com/2011/07/24/asp-net-mvc-add-html5-microdata-to-your-applications-using-metadata-providers/

Comment: @JasonFoglia - Sorry, I don't get what your problem is. Look at your question. You've posted a source for your custom attribute and a call to `Html.DisplayForModel`. You've stated that your custom attribute `didn't produce anything`. I've answered that this is because MVC knows *nothing* about your custom attribute and therefore will not use it in any way. The solution is to create custom metadata provider that will analyze your custom attribute (like in the url you've posted above). I assume you haven't created custom provider since you didn't mention it. What is that you don't understand?

Comment: I have created a custom metadata provider and I just posted it.

Comment: Have you registered your new provider? `ModelMetadataProviders.Current = new MetadataProvider();`, preferably in Global.asax `Application_Start`?

Comment: Yes of course. If you get it working please let me know and what you might of done different, thanks @JakubKonecki for all your help.

Comment: Post your custom `object` template.

Comment: As I've already told you, you need to create own `object` template that will use `AdditionalValues` from model metadata you populated in your provider. Read *Part 4* of the blog I linked to in my answer.

Comment: Thanks again for your help! I didn't get it working yet but after reading the whole blog, I see exactly what I need to do.

Answer (score 0):

After discussing the issue with @JakubKonecki and reading the blog post he presented.
Here is my EditTemplate used to help create data dash attributes in MVC 2/3 and most likely 4.

I saved this file under root/Views/Shared/EditTemplates as String.cshtml. cshtml since i'm using the razor engine. The location can be different if you are using Area's and they don't have to be stored in "Shared" views folder. Just read the entire 
blog @JakubKonecki posted by Brad Wilson.

Thanks again @JakubKonecki!

```
@{
    Dictionary<string, object> AV = ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues;
    Dictionary<string, object> htmlAttr = new Dictionary<string,object>();
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> A in AV)
    {
        if (A.Value is System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> B in (System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary)A.Value)
            {
                htmlAttr.Add(B.Key, B.Value);
            }
        }
    }
    htmlAttr.Add("class", "text-box single-line");
    htmlAttr.Add("type", "text");
}

@Html.TextBox("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue, htmlAttr)
```